# Retrieve conditions matched on laravel model query

Tags: mysql, laravel, search

This might be an SQL limitation but I'm working on a Laravel project and so I'm posing the questions to solve what I'm trying to accomplish.

I am preforming a search on a model (and it's relationships)

```
Auth::user()->employers()
    ->where('name', 'like' $filter)
    ->orWhereHas('locations.location', function($query) use ($filter) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', $filter);
    })
    ->orWhereHas('locations.branches', function($query) use ($filter) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', $filter);
    })
    ->orWhereHas('locations.positions', function($query) use ($filter) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', $filter);
    })->get();
```

I would like to be able to identify which of this conditions was the one that matched the record so that I can tell the frontend, "Hey this record is being shown to you because x property nested in it matched your search critera." Where x is the condition that made it a match.

The code above returns a collection of records that matched. 
I want to know where EACH of those records matched.

Comment: i don't get the question

Comment: Alright, 
I want to preform a search based on various search criteria, where they are all optional (WHERE location.name = 'Peter' OR 'location.branches' = 'Peter' OR 'location.comments' = 'Peter'). 

So I want to show which of the search criteria was that one that matched the record in my db.

Does this make sense?

Comment: so how do you want it ? as a separate column ?

Comment: I don't really care at this point, I'm mostly trying to get it any way possible.

Answer (score 1):

Now your query looks like this:

```
select *
from employees
where name like ?
  or exists (select * from locations ...)
  or exists (...)
```

When you add the subqueries to the `SELECT` part, you get boolean values:

```
select *,
  exists (select * from locations ...) as hasLocations
  exists (...) as hasBranches
  ...
from employees
where name like ?
  or exists (select * from locations ...)
  or exists (...)
```

You have to take a look at the `whereHas` implementation to find a way generating these subqueries from the relationships.

Comment: You're suggesting doing a check at the select level that resolves to a boolean that I can later check to see if is true or false? 

I'll see what I can find in whereHas, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply want to show your model and say "you are seeing this because...".  If that is indeed the case and the model may only have a location, or a branch, or a position when the query is complete then you may simply query it in an if statement. Assuming your 'search' criteria is `$name`:

```
$matches = array();

if($user->location == $name) {
  array_push($matches, 'location');
};
if($user->branch == $name) {
  array_push($matches, 'branch');
};
if($user->position == $name) {
  array_push($matches, 'position');
};

return $matches;
```

You have basically done your query, and now need simply examine the object for which parameter satisfies your condition.  If there are more than a few hard conditions though I'd search out a more object-oriented approach, though in this case a simple procedural method on the object would do.  Could do this on the `User` model returning an array with matched values if there are more than one:

```
public function foundBy($name) {

    $matches = array();

    if($this->location == $name) {
      array_push($matches, 'location');
    };
    if($this->branch == $name) {
      array_push($matches, 'branch');
    };
    if($this->position == $name) {
      array_push($matches, 'position');
    };
    return $matches;

}
```

This to call it:

```
$foundBy = $user->foundBy($name);
```

And should return an array.

In this way, what the method returns will tell you how the object matches by looking at the values in the array.

Hope this helped!

Comment: what if it include two or more ? like location and branch ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm following so let me know if I got the idea. 

I think in the first part of your response you're talking about iterating through the response of my query and checking each node to see where it matches. 

And the second part you're suggesting making a change to one of the models being searched on so that the model itself can tell you how it was matched?

PS. All the relations are one to many. So and employer would have many locations and so on.

Comment: If two or more, you could simply have an array and append it for each value that matches, and then just return the array.

Comment: @Pablo your first part is correct, you are simply checking which property matches the name.  For the second part, mostly there.  The model you are using in this case is the User model as the Auth::user() returns a instance of it for the currently authorized user.  By adding my method to the User model, each time a user object is instantiated, you will have the ability to check if it has matching parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Luke, I'll try those and see if I get anywhere with it.